# Sweetalerts - How to add validation in Chaining modals (queue) inputs on each step

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am trying to add input fields in chaining modals (queue) using sweet alerts.

Reference http://www.inetcnx.net/sweetalert/index.html#chaining-modals

**Problem:** I want to add validation on each input field. Lets say; to make it required field, therefore user must need to enter value in input before proceeding to next step.

**Code:**

```
$('body').on('click','.apt_action',function() {
swal.setDefaults({
      input: 'text',
      confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
      showCancelButton: true,
      animation: true,
      progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
    })

    var steps = [
      {
        title: 'Customer Name', 
       inputId: "customer_name",
       inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
      },
      {
        title: 'Sales Person',
        text: 'Product sold by?'
      },
      { 
        title: 'Additional Details',
        text: 'Coments or additional notes'
      }, 

    ]

    swal.queue(steps).then(function (result) {
      swal.resetDefaults()
      swal({
        title: 'All done!',
        html:
          'Your answers: <pre>' +
            (result) +
          '</pre>',
        confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!',
        showCancelButton: false
      })
    }, function () {
      swal.resetDefaults()
    })
    });
```

Js Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/mvohq23z/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a **preConfirm function** block at each step you want to validate and do the validation using the variable **value** as you wish. Call the **resolve()** method for success or the **reject('text error description here')** to display an error message and prevent the chain modal to proceed to the next step.

Here's an example using your code in order to make all the input fields required:

JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/davidtoledo/ymb38u6t/1

```
        swal.setDefaults({
            input: 'text',
            confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
            showCancelButton: true,
            animation: true,
            progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
        });

        var steps = [
            {
                title: 'Customer Name',
                inputId: "customer_name",
                inputPlaceholder: "Write something",
                preConfirm: function(value)
                {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
                    {
                        if (value) {
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject('Please type something in the step 1!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Sales Person',
                text: 'Product sold by?',
                preConfirm: function(value)
                {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
                    {
                        if (value) {
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject('Please type something in the step 2!');
                        }
                    });
                }

            },
            {
                title: 'Additional Details',
                text: 'Coments or additional notes',
                preConfirm: function(value)
                {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
                    {
                        if (value) {
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject('Please type something in the step 3!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },

        ];

        swal.queue(steps).then(function (result) {
            swal.resetDefaults();
            swal({
                title: 'All done!',
                html:
                    'Your answers: <pre>' +
                    (result) +
                    '</pre>',
                confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!',
                showCancelButton: false
            })
        }, function () {
            swal.resetDefaults()
        });
```

Cheers,

David Costa